# Healthchecks for windows services from MVC

Tags: .net-core, health-check

I have a .NET Core MVC frontend which is dependant on two Windows services that they run in parallel.
I would like to provide a health check whether both Windows services are running in the startup.cs
of the MVC project.
How do I add the status of the services to the healthcheck? Here is what I have so far:

```
    ServiceController[] windowsservices = ServiceController.GetServices();
    foreach (ServiceController service in windowsservices)
    {
        var serviceStatus = service.ServiceName + "==" + service.Status;
    }

    var connectionString = "myConnectionString";

    services.AddHealthChecks()
        .AddSqlServer(connectionString, failureStatus: HealthStatus.Unhealthy);
```

and

```
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a health check is already available in the `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.System` package. Once you add the NuGet package to your web project you can register a Windows Service health check with with [AddWindowsServiceHealthCheck](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/50594f0643515e83f9bf6ce864f9594bf980b865/src/HealthChecks.System/DependencyInjection/SystemHealthCheckBuilderExtensions.cs#L185):

```
var healthBuilder=services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddSqlServer(connectionString, failureStatus: HealthStatus.Unhealthy);

foreach (ServiceController service in windowsservices)
{
    healthBuilder.AddWindowsServiceHealthCheck(service.ServiceName);
}
```